Why does this zone file error with "not a valid number"?
The zone file in question:
$ORIGIN maximal.enterprises
$TTL 2h
@               SOA     ns1 (   2024090600 ; Serial
                                8h         ; Refresh
                                30m        ; Retry
                                1w         ; Expire
                                1h )       ; Negative Cache TTL
                NS      ns1
sea1.router     A       144.202.90.240
                AAAA    fe80::5400:5ff:fe15:5e61
ns1             A       144.202.90.240
                AAAA    fe80::5400:5ff:fe15:5e61

And when I load this with named-checkzone maximal.enterprises maximal.enterprises.zone, I get the following error:
dns_rdata_fromtext: /var/named/maximal.enterprises.zone:4: near '8h': not a valid number
zone maximal.enterprises/IN: loading from master file /var/named/maximal.enterprises.zone failed: not a valid number
zone maximal.enterprises/IN: not loaded due to errors.

I'm using BIND 9.20.1.

You're missing the rname field (responsible administrator email address) of the SOA record, as a result "2024090600" becomes the rname and "8h" becomes your serial number, in which context it is indeed not a valid number (as the serial is not a time interval).

Note that parentheses ( ) don't have a semantic meaning in zone files – they exist only to allow line-wrapping of records – so the serial number is not "1st field within the (…)" but always "3rd field within the entire record" irrespective of where the parens are placed (if at all).
